# Cannot convert return expression of type 'Bool' to return type 'Bool'

Tags: swift, casting

Here's a special kind of nonsense that's left me curious. I figured a screenshot would be the easiest way to show what's happening.

This error seems to be total nonsense. I DO see the distinction "return expression" and "return type" in the error but I don't know if that's meaningful or just bad language choices by the developers.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

**EDIT:**

As requested, I created a small test case in an isolated Swift file as such:

```
func TestFunc(item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if !(item[1] as! Bool){
        return (item[2] as! Array).count > 0
    }

    return false
}
```

Which gave the same error. Following ColGraff's suggestion, of providing a type to the array, I changed the code to:

```
func TestFunc(item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if !(item[1] as! Bool){
        return (item[2] as! Array<AnyObject>).count > 0
    }

    return false
}
```

Which did remove the error message but none of the responses so far have answered the original question, as to what the error message actually means.

Comment: You're much better off posting the text of the code rather than a screenshot. That way people can copy it and test it easily. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are a bunch of errors here. Please post your full code in text format.

Comment: I have edited the original post to provide copy/paste-friendly code. There was quite a bit of downvoting on a question about the nature of an error message not a request for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the code

```
item[2] as! Array
```

You need to specify the type of element in the array. I'm assuming it's `AnyObject` so you should do:

```
return (item[2] as! Array<AnyObject>).count > 0
```

However, there are many errors in this code and also a lot of anti-patterns. One major one is you are using the forced unwrapping operator, `!`. Avoid using it at all, if you can. You should be testing each `Optional` and handling if it's set or unset.

```
guard let item2 = item[2] as? [AnyObject] else { return false }
return !item2.isEmpty
```

This question was more difficult to answer than it should have been because you didn't post the code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) manner. Screenshots are not very useful because the answerer has to re-type your code, taking up time and possibly introducing errors. Not to mention that much of the code surrounding your error has to be reproduced before any debugging can occur. You'll get much more useful information out of this site if you make it easier for people to answer your questions.

Comment: I have edited the original post to provide copy/paste-friendly code. The changes removed the error but your response did address the original question which is what the error actually means.